# Hangouts screenshare crashes in chrome after updating nvidia drivers

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I use hangouts in combination with Chrome (v61.0.3163.91) daily for my work and I often need to share my screen with colleagues. For some reason, after having updated my graphics card, screensharing during a call completely crashes chrome. It closes all windows and background processes.

Some details:
Laptop: Asus N750JK-T4068H (Windows 10 x64 fully up to date)
Graphics:  Nvidia Geforce 850m running software version: 385.69
I tried switching chrome to the integrated Intel card in the Nvidia Control Panel to no avail.I also completely removed and reinstalled chrome which also did nothing to help. I also disabled extensions and disconnected my secondary monitors.

I hope someone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I reverted my driver using DDU and went back to 375.05 and all is well again